# Xamarin forms Android - Alarmmanager not triggering at the specific time intervals

Tags: android, xamarin, alarmmanager

I have a requirement to call a service for every 20minutes.
I have created an Alarm manager, to trigger a service to run at repeated intervals.
I have issues with the code which I have below.

1. I have tried added **notifyTimeInInMilliseconds** to trigger for the first time which is not called at right time (not required but to check)
2. Then intervals I set here for 2 minutes to test and which is also not triggered at right time - called randomly.

---

```
public static void SetAlarmForBackgroundServices(Context context)
{
   var alarmIntent = new Intent(context.ApplicationContext, typeof(BackgroundReceiver));
   var broadcast = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context.ApplicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.NoCreate);
        if (broadcast == null)
        {
           var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context.ApplicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            
            var utcTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
            var epochDif = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) - DateTime.MinValue).TotalSeconds;
            var notifyTimeInInMilliseconds = utcTime.AddSeconds(-epochDif).Ticks / 10000;
              
            alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, notifyTimeInInMilliseconds, 1000 * 60 * 2, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

### `

Could anyone suggest me what's wrong here or what is the right way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: var notifyTimeInInMilliseconds = Calendar.GetInstance(Android.Icu.Util.TimeZone.Default).TimeInMillis + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);

Comment: Hi Sushil, I don't have the reference to Android.Icu.Util so i tried the below                                                                                              'var notifyTimeInInMilliseconds = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default).TimeInMillis + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds;  '                  It triggered at 1minute, also repeated after 2 min of interval for 3 times. And later there was a mismatch again. And some times later. triggered again at right time. Any suggestions here?

Comment: From the docs: `Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager